# .NET RIA services metadata and foreign keys

Tags: .net, silverlight, ria

I’m using Silverlight and the .NET RIA Services.

I’ve generated an entity data model from a database, created one domain class service for all the tables and chosen to generate the metadata.

Now, when trying to build I get errors in metadata that contain foreign keys in the generated file App.Web.g.cs.  The problem is there are lots of evaluations comparing Entities to simple values.  For example, Order.Customer is a foreign key for Customer.ID and the following fails:

private bool FilterOrder(Order entity)
{
return (entity.Customer == this.ID);
}

I would expect to see:

private bool FilterOrder(Order entity)
{
return (entity.Customer.ID == this.ID);
}

I don’t really know what to do here as the problem is in a generated file.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to explicitly create the foreign key as a Scalar Property of your Order entity and then mark it as the Dependent Property in the Referential Constraint on the Orders-Customer association (double-click the association in the EF designer).

Comment: PS. I mean creating a property like 'Order.CustomerId'